# PostgreSQL UNNEST Array and Insert Into New Table

Tags: postgresql

I have an array column I want to unnest, split the element values, and copy into another table. For example:

```
id | col1
-----------------
1  | '{"a:1", "b:2"}'
```

I'd like to insert into a new table that looks like:

```
table1_id | col1 | col2
------------------------
1         | 'a'  | 1
1         | 'b'  | 2
```

Comment: It's unclear whether those single quotes are real - at either stage. Please provide a complete setup with `CREATE TABLE` (showing data type and constraints) and `INSERT` statements (showing exact values).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name col1 is string, col2 is integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue an `insert` from this `select`:

```
select id as table1_id,
       (string_to_array(ary, ':'))[1] as col1,
       (string_to_array(ary, ':'))[2] as col2
  from table1
       cross join lateral unnest(col1) as u(ary);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=edb0c9800655818aebdf232a1d833c50)*

Comment: That works great! What does `u(ary)` do?

Comment: The `u(ary)` aliases the result of the `unnest(col1)` as table `u` with one column, `ary`.  Without that aliasing, the result of the `unnest` is called `unnest` instead of `ary`.